# Extend lodash types (@types/lodash) with an interface of "first" method for my project

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

**ISSUE:**
I found @types/lodash method first doesn't cover the case type of the input is union of two (multiple) typed arrays:
// In my file I have
import * as _ from 'lodash';

```
interface First {
  name: string;
}

interface Second {
  age: number;
}

function performSomeLogic(): First[] | Second[] {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) return [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
  return [{age: 42}, {age: 33}];
}

// we got some array First or Second of type. ok
const returnedData = performSomeLogic(); // we got some array First or Second of type. ok

// we expect value is First or Second of type. NOT ok.

// *******************
// TS ERROR
// TS2345: Argument of type 'First[] | Second[]' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'ArrayLike<First>'.
// *******************
const firstValueOfData = _.first(returnedData); 

// further steps could be ..
const proceedWithValueOfData = (value: First | Second) => Object.keys(value);
proceedWithValueOfData(firstValueOfData);
```

**IDEA:**
I came up with the proper interface for **_.first()**. I try to put it into the typings.d.ts add refer it for bundler:

```
// typings.d.ts
type DeriveArrTypes<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : T;

// So DeriveArrTypes<First[] | Second[]> returns First|Second union

declare module 'lodash' {
  // LoDashStatic IS THE INTERFACE LODASH HAS HAD. FIRST IS DECLARED IN IT. I WANT TO ADD ITS EXTENDED DECLARATION
  interface LoDashStatic {
    first<T extends []>(value: T): DeriveArrTypes<T> | undefined;
  }
}
```

**SUCCESS - NO:**
But that doesn't work. Typescript stops displaying any errors (including others different). I use WebStorm as IDE it continue highlighting.

**ENV:**
It is a frontend project that is served by Typescript for transpiling and Webpack for bundling (due to its long continuous liveness :)).
From *webpack.config.js*:

```
       // the rule for ts
       {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
                    transpileOnly: true
                }
            }],
        },

       // plugins section
       plugins: [
         // bla-bla plugins
         ...

        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          tsconfig: __dirname + '/tsconfig.json'
        })
      ]
```

From *tsconfig.json*:

```
"compilerOptions": {
      // bla-bla options
      ... 

      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
 }

 // I ADDED THIS
 "include": [
    "app/typings/**/*"
  ],
```

As I created *app/typings* directory and put *typings.d.ts* into it.

Comment: `declare module "lodash"` is what you want. It's a module specifier you are augmenting and thus a string

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks a lot. I follow your advice as it is the correct notation, I missed that. However, it doesn't fix the issue. I'd say I can't see any impact of that.

Comment: It's a prerequisite though. I wasn't saying that's all you have to do, I only glanced at your question, but it is necessary.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks. I appreciate that. I've updated my syntax in the question above.

Comment: Note you need to be in a module context for this to work, otherwise it's not an augmentation. Just add `export {}` to the top of the file just to make sure it remains a module even if you remove imports

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add interface to a npm module you can use `declare module` keyword

```
import lodash  from "lodash";
declare module "lodash " {
    interface First {
       name: string;
    }

    interface Second {
      age: number;
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws an error `This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.` So I add as `import * as lodash from 'lodash';`
Now it says `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'first'.` and refers to the place in the @types/lodash where an interface with the same name has been implemented.

Comment: You can fix it by changing`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` and `"esModuleInterop": true,` to your tsconfig.json
@AlekseyLysenko I have just run it and it's working just fine

https://gist.github.com/golkhandani/f11cfeefd753e90aca0e3bb7facd8b17

Comment: Thank you very much for you assistance. With the flags you mention, it doesn't throw an error within _typings_ file. The key point I have,  I want to extend existing interface of _lodash_ types **LoDashStatic**. There is _first_ declared, but its declaration is not enough. If there is an approach to add new interface _lodash_ can consume, I'd be super glad to go with it.